# Is it possible to recreate in VSTS the Versions Report that you find in JIRA?

Tags: azure-devops

One feature in JIRA that I loved was the Version Report functionality. Assign a value in the "Version" field of a work item and when all of the work items have estimates allocated to them as the team works through them the Version Report calculates a range of possible completion dates based on the team's historic, average velocity.

I'd love to be able to recreate this in VSTS

Answer (score 0):

You can get [work item revisions through REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/revisions#get-a-work-item-revision) and statistics estimates if related field (e.g. Remainning Work, Estimate per to process template) changed in each revision.